# selecting fields in a document after applying filter on embedded document

Tags: c#, mongodb, nested

Can you let me know the C# equivalent of below query please?

```
db.RolesNPerm.find(
   { "Roles.Name":{$in:[ "PO","role1","TO"] }},
   { _id: 1, ParentId: 1 }
)
```

I am trying to select the fields(`_id` and `ParentId`) in the record if the `Name` in the embedded document(`Roles`) matches any of the value in the list.

Here is my MongoDB document

```
{
    "_id" : "1",
    "ParentId" : "par1",
    "Roles" : [ 
        {
            "Name" : "PO",
            "_id" : "5bc08ee1f12541c3aaa03084"
        }
    ]
}
```

Below is the result of my query as the Role.Name matches "PO" in the list of names.

```
{
    "_id" : "1",
    "ParentId" : "par1"
}
```

Comment: What have you tried? SO is not code conversion service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are (at least) two ways to do that:

You can use `Builder` class to build filter and projection part. The problem is that you can't express `Roles.Name` part using strongly typed lambda expressions so you can use `FieldDefinition` type as a fallback

```
var values = new[] { "PO", "role1", "TO" };
FieldDefinition<Model, string> field = "Roles.Name";

var filter = Builders<Model>.Filter.In(field, values);
var project = Builders<Model>.Projection.Combine(
        Builders<Model>.Projection.Include(x => x._id),
        Builders<Model>.Projection.Include(x => x.ParentId)
    );

var result = Col.Find(filter).Project(project).ToList();
```

Alternatively you can use LINQ syntax which will be translated to relevant MongoDB command:

```
var values = new[] { "PO", "role1", "TO" };

var q = from doc in Col.AsQueryable()
        where doc.Roles.Any(x => values.Contains(x.Name))
        select new Model6()
        {
            ParentId = doc.ParentId,
            _id = doc._id
        };

var result = q.ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot It was very informative and much appreciated.I was trying to express Roles.Name in Lambda expression as hard coding the filed name is not a good practice. I understand from your response that it is not possible to express everything in Lambda.That was wonderful to know that we can use Linq in C# to interface with MongoDB.  The one issue i could see in Linq is that it not Asynchronous.

Comment: @user641247 remember about nameof operator in C#, you can build that string having compile time check